# How to get a loop for telnet port check in 1 line for Powershell?

Tags: powershell, tcp, telnet

I would like to streamline the following command into 1 line, to do a loop until it returns a TRUE.

The following will check if the TCP connection is working correctly:

```
(New-Object System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient -ArgumentList DESTINATION-IP,PORT).Connected
```

This will normally print/return a TRUE if there is no blocking of any firewall.

What I want to do is, without a script/file, to have this command being looped until it returns a TRUE value.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why not use [nmap](https://nmap.org/)? It's designed to do just that (and more).

Comment: `while ($true)`? How about just ... yeah, learning some basics of powershell. Fun fact: It's similiar to most common scripting languages.

Comment: You mean something like while((New-Object System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient -ArgumentList DESTINATION-IP,PORT).Connected){}

Comment: @vonPryz out of company policy we may not use it.

Comment: @Clijsters ..........

Answer (score 1):

Something like this would work:

```
while ((New-Object System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient -ArgumentList DESTINATION-IP,PORT).Connected -ne $true) { Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 1000 }
```

I would not recommend sleeping less than ~250 milliseconds or so unless you actually want to connection flood.

Also, remember that you don't need to make a one-liner to call a script without a script file.  Powershell has an end of line terminator: `;`.  You can easily call `powershell -Command { 1; 2; 3; }`.

---

Try this to be a bit more robust.  You can remove the whitespace and line breaks to make it into a single line, but I'll post it formatted for legibility:

```
do {
    try {
        $Connected = (New-Object System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient -ArgumentList DESTINATION-IP,PORT -ErrorAction Stop).Connected;
    }
    catch {
        $Connected = $false;
    }
    if (!$Connected) { Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 1000; }
} until ($true.Equals($Connected));
```

Comment: New-Object : Exception calling ".ctor" with "2" argument(s): "No connection could be made because the target machine ac
tively refused it 10.10.10.10:212"At line:1 char:11

Comment: Probably the return of the connection not being allowed, does not return a FALSE, but more of an error and thats why the function fails. Is there a way to say: Anything(false, error) but True, go in to the loop?

Comment: @SerdarEbeng Kind of.  See my updated code.  Part of the problem is going to be that you can't completely stop some implicit typecasting.    To get explicitly "do until the $Connected is of type System.Boolean with a value of true", you need to use `$true.Equals()`.  Normally you can just say `until ($Connected)` or `until ($Connected -eq $true)`.